# using attr of the value of child element in a list to change css of div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am designing ranking bar, i have 9 bars, however i want the bar height to vary such that bar 0 and bar 8 are the longest. i can seem to manipulate my jquery selector to change the css style of the bar using the value of the select option. 
Below are my code.

css:

```
 .rating-c .br-widget {
height: 60px;
display: inline;    
}

.rating-c .br-widget a {
display: inline;    
width: 20px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 2px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 2.2;
text-align: center;
color: #444444;
border: thin solid #b6b6b6;
}
.rating-c .br-widget a.br-active,
.rating-c .br-widget a.br-selected {
background-color: #59a6d6;
color: white;
}
```

html:

```
        <div class="rating-c">
             <label class="ratingLabel">
                 <select id="rating-c" name="rating">
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <option value="1">4</option>
                      <option value="2">3</option>
                      <option value="3">2</option>
                      <option value="4">1</option>
                      <option value="5">0</option>                            
                      <option value="6">1</option>
                      <option value="7">2</option>
                      <option value="8">3</option>
                      <option value="9">4</option>
                    </select>
                 Price</label>    
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.rating-c .br-widget a select[name=rating]').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")==="2"){
                $(".rating-c").css("height", "55px");
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")==="3"){
                $(".rating-c .br-widget a").css("height", "50px");
            }
        });
```

this doesn't seem to work, can anyone help. thank you.   Help please

Comment: Protip1: `this.value`

Comment: Protip2: convert to integers. That's like using a stringified "true" as a boolean check. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: .br-widget class does not exist also i don't see a element in the html code

Comment: @user3087839 it in the css ref i copied from http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/. i dont know it use as well, but the bar displays well.

Comment: attributes and properties are different things. You want the property.

Comment: yes, property values. @NickDugger

Comment: @NickDugger it doesn't work till, could this issue be from my select itself? $('.rating-c .br-widget a select[name=rating]')

Answer (score 0):

Using what @SterlingArcher said, let's use `this.value` and `parseInt`...

```
if (parseInt(this.value) === 2) {
    $("something").css("key", "value");
};
```

first, `parseInt` converts the value into a number, which makes your particular comparison make much more sense.

Second, we use `this.value` which uses the value property, and not the attribute. This could also be accomplished in jQuery buy doing `$(this).val()` which retrieves the property, instead of the value attribute, which you were previously doing.

Comment: it doesn't work till, could this issue be from my select itself? $('.rating-c .br-widget a select[name=rating]')